# Ferramentas para compilar o código CSS automaticamente no Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, css

Estou com muita dificuldade para passar meu código para produção. Quero remover meus comentários e alterar o nome das classes, mas não encontrei uma **ferramenta para compilar o código como produção** gerando um arquivo zip como output, com a mesma estrutura de pastas.

Para minificar o nome das classes eu uso o:

> https://github.com/JPeer264/node-rcs-core

Mas o processo é totalmente manual e eu preciso tomar muito cuidado para não ficar faltando nenhum arquivo, se não eu preciso recompilar novamente.

Minha solução seria ao invés de pegar uma única pagina com html, css e js individuais. Ler toda a pasta e apenas depois gerar os novos arquivos com a mesma estrutura.

```js
const rcs=require('rcs-core');
const fs=require('fs');

rcs.fillLibraries(fs.readFileSync('./antes/sacola.css', 'utf8'));

//Antes
const css = rcs.replace.css(fs.readFileSync('./antes/sacola.css', 'utf8'));
const js1 = rcs.replace.js(fs.readFileSync('./antes/sacola.js', 'utf8'));
const js2 = rcs.replace.js(fs.readFileSync('./antes/sacola-util.js', 'utf8'));
const html = rcs.replace.html(fs.readFileSync('./antes/index.html', 'utf8'));
 
//Depois
fs.writeFileSync('./depois/sacola.css', css);
fs.writeFileSync('./depois/sacola.js', js1);
fs.writeFileSync('./depois/sacola-util.js', js2);
fs.writeFileSync('./depois/index.html', html);
```

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o `fs.readdir` (ou `fs.readdirSync`) para fazer algo do tipo?

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxilio, mas ainda estou com dúvidas de como fazer o output.

Comment: Eu utilizo o rcs pois ele desempenha o papel de rescrever o nome das classes muito bem. Mas  o que é mais importante agora é gerar este código compilado e minificado. Estou a tantos dias buscando uma ferramenta pra isso, que não estou mais nem me importando em pagar kkk.